# builing Gem5 in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, out-of-memory, ubuntu-20.04, gem5

I am new to Gem5, I run the command on terminal scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j9 to build Gem5. I got this error:
g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program lto1
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/tmp/ccG0ZHm9.mk:41: /tmp/gem5.opt.ktpAnb.ltrans13.ltrans.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
lto-wrapper: fatal error: make returned 2 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [build/X86/gem5.opt] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
MY PC : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, 8 GB Main Memory, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

What's your Ubuntu storage size? I failed to build gem5 on Ubuntu 18.04 with 10GB and 20GB storage size, but succeed in 30GB. Maybe increase your storage size can fix the problem.